# Are there alternatives in English for a phrase that translates to "the immortals" from French?

Tags: synonymes

I posed [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46929/when-was-the-first-instance-of-generals-morand-friant-gudin-being-referred-to) today on History, and am searching for relevant phrases in English translations of 19th century accounts. Are there any other English phrases that I should be searching for, besides those with the root "*immortal*", that a translator might have chosen in place of "*the Immortals*"? I do not know how literal the translation from French to "*the immortals*" might be.

Comment: Hmm, this question is posed in quite a backward way. You want us to use "immortal" to surmise what the French original was (*probably* « immortel ») and from there to ask for other translations of « immortel » into English. Probably outside the scope of this SE. But since « immortel » covers pretty much the same ground as the English does. I would simply look for English synonyms.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: This is the answer I am looking for: "*... « immortel » covers pretty much the same ground as the English does*". I suspected enough, but don't know French at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The French word *immortel* is probably the one behind the English "immortal" given that Wikipedia says it was the nickname of the [Garde Impériale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendarmes_d%27%C3%A9lite_de_la_Garde_Imp%C3%A9riale).

These words were both, on introduction, likely recherché, borrowed from classical Latin rather than having developed naturally in their respective languages ([French etymology](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/immortel), [English etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/immortal)). Often, such words enjoy great overlap in the modern languages that share them, and this is the case here too. Because of that, any English synonym for "immortal" is likely also a valid translation of *immortel*.

That said, the specific reason for the epithet, according to [the French version](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendarmerie_d%27%C3%A9lite_de_la_Garde_imp%C3%A9riale) of the article linked above, was « leur faible ratio de pertes au combat » : their low ratio of combat losses. Thus, if I were looking for possible alternative names, I would focus on shades of "immortal" that concern being untouchable — "invincible", "undefeated", etc. — rather than, say, being eternal.

**Edit:** To integrate jlliagre's comment into the  answer, [since 1833](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/immortel) « les immortels » has been used to refer to [the members of the Académie française](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise#Les_%C2%AB_immortels_%C2%BB), derived from the motto « À l'immortalité » bestowed on its foundation, and nowadays the term mainly just refers to these members.

Comment: Note that nowadays, *les immortels* is almost exclusively understood to mean the [*Académie française*'s members](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise#Les_%C2%AB_immortels_%C2%BB).